# Parent of Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Tags: android, android-styles

What's the parent of `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`? I can't find a "parent" attribute in Android SDK resources. I guess it should be `Theme.AppCompat.Light`. But I didn't find any document to prove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit styles by using dot instead of using `parent` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes)). So `Theme.AppCompat.Light` is parent of `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

> You can also inherit styles (except those from the platform) by extending a style's name with a dot notation, instead of using the parent attribute. That is, prefix the name of your style with the name of the style you want to inherit, separated by a period.

Comment: Thanks, I must miss the paragraph.